# ASP.NET Table freeze pane (header and column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

[image]

I have dynamically generated my table as above. May I know how can I make the table freeze pane on the header and columns (those in dark blue)? Something like what the Excel is capable of.

FYI I have already setup a proper thead, tbody and those in dark blue are th.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution that I'm expecting but it serve the purpose as well. Kindly refer the link for the guide.

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/04/08/jquery-freeze-html-table-header-and-the-left-columns/